# Quickbooks POS old transactions view

Tags: quickbooks

I have a client running Quickbooks along with Quickbooks POS set up. We had to condense are Quickbooks file, and now we can't pull up transactions prior to the condensing. This makes sense to an extent for me, but is there a way that they could still pull up old transactions on POS from at least a decade ago without bloating the quickbooks file?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. You should contact QuickBooks POS support for the answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Was just hoping to avoid their tech support lol.

Comment: FWIW, I'm about 99% sure that the answer you're going to get is that once you condense the file, the old stuff is lost, and that there's no way to work around that. The way condensing works in the financial editions of QuickBooks is that it essentially discards all of the detailed transaction data, and squishes everything down to just very general journal entries, so you lose all that old data. The way I've seen people work around it in the past is to copy their data file, and then open the old data file when they need to look up something new, while opening the new one going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the nature of my client's business means they could be looking up transactions from 5,10, or even 15 years ago. (They sell mattresses, and people like to know what they bought last time). So my concern with that is, they'd have to open up 2 or 3+ files just to potentially find the right transaction... I'll contact Quickbooks anyways though, maybe I could have them export old transactions to an excel sheet for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't terribly intuitive for the client to manually switch back and forth from an old & new POS file, and it was quite obvious what file they were in (the potential for accidentally recording a sale against an old file was high).

So my solution to this was to actually pull the information from and old copy with a ODBC connection tool (plenty out there on the web). I was then able to export that to Excel and organize it in a readable / searchable manner for the client.

FYI, Quickbooks wasn't helpful on this matter.